# Stop WooCommerce admin email notification for free orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I want to stop woocommerce email notification if order value is `$0.00`

I used this code :

```js
function restrict_admin_new_order_mail( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( $order->get_total() === '0.00' ) {
        return;
    } else {
        return $recipient;
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'restrict_admin_new_order_mail', 1, 2);
```

The code working but I got this fatal error, all email options disappeared at Woocommerce settings (see attached screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

```
Error Details
=============

[13-Jan-2021 17:34:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_total() on null in C:\Users\joe\Local Sites\staging\app\public\wp-content\themes\flatsome-child\functions.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\joe\Local Sites\staging\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(289): restrict_admin_new_order_mail('email@gmail....', NULL)
#1 C:\Users\joe\Local Sites\staging\app\public\wp-includes\plugin.php(206): WP_Hook->apply_filters('email@gmail....', Array)
#2 C:\Users\joe\Local Sites\staging\app\public\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\emails\class-wc-email.php(399): apply_filters('woocommerce_ema...', 'email@gmail....', NULL, Object(WC_Email_New_Order))
#3 C:\Users\joe\Local Sites\staging\app\public\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\settings\class-wc-settings-emails.php(294): WC_Email->get_recipient()
#4 C:\Users\joe\Local Sites\staging\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287): WC_Settings_Emails->email_notification_setting(Array)
#5 C:\Users\joe\Local Sites\staging\app\public\wp-includes\ in C:\Users\joe\Local Sites\staging\app\public\wp-content\themes\flatsome-child\functions.php on line 8
```

Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error, you need to add this simple line inside your function at the beginning:

```
if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;
```

I have also revisited your code a bit… Try this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'restrict_admin_new_order_mail', 1, 2);
function restrict_admin_new_order_mail( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) 
        return $recipient;

    if( $order->get_total() > 0 ) {
        return $recipient;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'wc_disable_customer_order_email_if_free', 10, 2 );
  
function wc_disable_customer_order_email_if_free( $recipient, $order ) {
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ( 'wc-settings' === $page ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }
    if ( (float) $order->get_total() === '0.00' ) $recipient = '';
    return $recipient;
}
```

You can target different emails **woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order**

Comment: Thank you, the code you provided not working, I still receive emails, the code I provided is actually working but it cause a fatal error ( details above).

Answer (score 0):

I removed (float) to make it work, this code stop notification email for admin

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_disable_customer_order_email_if_free', 10, 2 );

function wc_disable_customer_order_email_if_free( $recipient, $order ) {
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ( 'wc-settings' === $page ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }
    if ( $order->get_total() === '0.00' ) $recipient = '';
    return $recipient;
}
```